# How to avoid Transient data getting flushed during saveAndFlush in Hibernate?

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a transient attribute in my data model. It gets flushed during the saveAndFlush() operation. Is there anything that can be done to avoid that transient attribute getting flushed ?

Comment: What do you mean it is flushed- JPA will not map transient properties in your entities unless you've put a mapping on them. For others, you can tell JPA they should not have a default mapping applied using the @Transient annotation

Comment: Yeah. The data is added to the attribute using a mapping and during saveAndFlush() it gets removed. I need that attribute's data for a process down the line. So looking for something to avoid the data getting removed. @Chris

Comment: I do not follow that - a mapping in JPA is the definition, like '@Basic' or '@OneToOne' telling JPA that your property is to be persisted in the DB. Flush in JPA is a method calls that tells it to synchronize to the database (ie saveAndFlush). So is the property being put in the database or not? Maybe show exactly what you mean with a code example. I suspect your talking about actual 'transient' properties in your Entity and the entity being returned from save (or read from the database) not having these values set - which should be expected since they are transient.